# Использование gaussianBlur Java

Tags: java, изображения

есть входное изображение `ImageToProcess` типа `BufferedImage`, которое я хочу обработать с использованием библиотеки  GaussianBlur:

```
MarvinImage InputImage = new MarvinImage(ImageToProcess);
MarvinImage OutputImage = new MarvinImage();

GaussianBlur gaussianBlur = new GaussianBlur();
gaussianBlur.load();
gaussianBlur.setAttribute("radius", resizerApp.BlurRadius);
gaussianBlur.process(OutputImage, InputImage);
MarvinImageIO.saveImage(OutputImage,"image.jpg");
```

В итоге я получаю такую ошибку (425 - размер изображения в пикселях):

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 425 out of bounds for length 425
```

Я пробовал еще вызвать обработку изображения следующим образом:

```
MarvinPluginCollection.gaussianBlur(InputImage, OutputImage, resizerApp.BlurRadius);
```

Но ошибка не исчезает от этого. Подскажите пожалуйста, как ее устранить.

Answer (score 0):

Ты перепутал местами аргументы. Правильно так:

```
gaussianBlur.process(inputImage, outputImage);
```

А лучше всего не создавать ещё одну переменную OutputImage, а записать обработанное изображение в исходную переменную:

```
gaussianBlur.process(inputImage.clone(), inputImage);
MarvinImageIO.saveImage(inputImage,"image.jpg");
```

Покажи, как у тебя ImageToProcess создаётся. Возможно, ещё там ошибки есть. А также какое значение хранится в `resizerApp.BlurRadius`?

(Я с профиру, если что :D)

Comment: спасибо, помогло)